# Can I add a new row to a table if a checkbox is checked using one query rather than nested? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

After much head-scratching, I've got this query working - but it looks clunky and feels slow when it runs.

I have a table called UserTable which has a field called 'Item' populated if the specific user says 'yes' to that item. I only want to add a row for that item into UserTable in that instance - in other words, I don't want to have lots of user_ID/Item/'no' relationships in the table, only the user_ID/Item/'yes' responses.

I've built some code which shows the user the whole dataset and allows them to change their preference and then press update. When they update, an array called $checkbox is output which includes the item numbers (eg "1","3","6") which they've ticked as 'yes'. If they don't tick anything, $checkbox is set to "".

Here's the relevant code - as I say, it's very clunky, with a WHILE inside a FOREACH as well as two validating IF statements. Can I get rid of one (or both!) of the loops and replace with a SELECT type command?

```
foreach($checkbox as $value)
    {if($value!="") {
        $sql=   "SELECT count(Item) as row_exists 
                FROM UserTable
                WHERE Item = '$value' and 
                User_ID = '$current_user_id'";

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        while ($iteminfo = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            If ((int)$iteminfo['row_exists']==0) { 
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO UserTable 
                            (User_ID,Item,Date) VALUES
                            ('$current_user_id','$value',now() )";
            $add_new_row = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't really understand your question

Comment: Short version: do I need to run a loop within a loop or is there a way of coding this which would run more quickly?

Comment: Why not set the table so the Item is a unique field?? That way you wouldnt have to check to see if it exists.

Comment: @craig1231 - not sure if I've understood you correctly (still very much learning the ropes), but the same Item can appear many times in UserTable because many users can select it - does that make sense?

Comment: Yup. You can make a unique key derived from Item and User_id. So a single user can have many items and a single item can have many users. But only one instance of Item AND User_id would be in the table, if that makes sense? So if the key was duplicated an insert would fail silently, which i think is what you are attempting?

Comment: Ah, that does make sense - nice lateral thinking! Does that mean that it would keep the older entry and discard the duplicate one - I want to keep the oldest date stamp if possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate both if statements:

1. Filter your checkbox array on != "" and loop over those results.  That gets rid of the first if that checks for != "".
2. Augment your initial query to include row_exists = 0, and iterate over those results. That gets rid of the second if.

In fact, you could probably merge your two sql statements into one composite conditional insertion.  You are allowed to do insertions of the form:

```
INSERT INTO table (SELECT ...)
```

So you could look at taking your first query and adapting/substituting it for the SELECT... part of the query above, and taking your second insertion and adapting/substituting it in place of the INSERT INTO... above.

Comment: Hi user1161318, I like the sound of your #2 and I like the sound of your final sentence even more... I'm not sure at the moment how to do either of those (n00b I'm afraid) but thank you for the pointers, I'll put on my thinking cap! Cheers.

Comment: If you need more help, we can take this to chat, and I can see what I can do.

Comment: Hello again, our last postings crossed over - that looks ideal, I'll give it a go and let you know how it pans out. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure!  I'd be very interested in your performance if you merge the queries.

Answer (score 0):

So if one user can be associated with multiple items, it seems that you should normalize this and have probably three tables - one for users, one for items, and one many-to-many table relating users to items.